# Replace placeholder by incremental value

Tags: text-editing

Windows 10
Emacs 26.1

I has the next text

```
[
  {
    "id": N,
    "name": "Agent#N",
    "address": "N Tabernacle St, London EC2A 4DD, UK"
  },
  {
    "id": N,
    "name": "Agent#N",
    "address": "N Tabernacle St, London EC2A 4DD, UK"
  },
  {
    "id": N,
    "name": "Agent#N",
    "address": "N Tabernacle St, London EC2A 4DD, UK"
  }
]
```

I need to replace **N** in every node by incremental integer value.
The result must be like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Agent#1",
    "address": "1 Tabernacle St, London EC2A 4DD, UK"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Agent#2",
    "address": "2 Tabernacle St, London EC2A 4DD, UK"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Agent#3",
    "address": "3 Tabernacle St, London EC2A 4DD, UK"
  }
]
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You could use keyboard macros, but the easiest approach in this case is probably to `query-replace-regexp` this:

```
"id": N,
"name": "Agent#N",
"address": "N Tabernacle St, London EC2A 4DD, UK"
```

with this:

```
"id": \#,
"name": "Agent#\#",
"address": "\# Tabernacle St, London EC2A 4DD, UK"
```

The counter is zero-based, so either add a dummy record at the start, or else use `\,(1+ \#)` instead of plain `\#`

---

n.b. There are no regexp-special characters in this text, so nothing needs escaping in the search pattern.

If, however, this is just one example amongst many, then there's a trick you can employ to automatically escape characters in the pattern as necessary:

- Copy the text to search for.
- <kbd>C-M-s</kbd> to run `isearch-forward-regexp`.
- <kbd>C-y</kbd> to yank the copied text as the search pattern.  Emacs will automatically escape any regexp-special characters.
- <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> to begin a `query-replace-regexp` for the isearch pattern.
- <kbd>C-y</kbd> to again paste the original copied text, this time as the replacement text.
- Edit the pasted replacement text to use the `\#` counter.
- Submit the replacement text, and begin replacing the matches as required...